# Android/ Web App - Setting orientation to portrait mode from landscape

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, orientation

I have a app which I have built in PhoneGap and within the Android Manifest file I have set the orientation to landscape, as my app is required to be in landscape mode at all time.

The issue I have is that I have a few external links, which load up in the default phone browser, however due to the fact that the phone is being held in landscape mode the page loads in landscape mode, which then does not fit all the content properly.

So my question is whether there is a way to set the orientation to automatically change to portrait when the external link is clicked. I am currently loading the external page within my javascript using:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.test.com";
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do like this. User can only set the orientation of browser into default portrait or landscape mode